# How do I register all subclasses of a certain parent to a different class

Tags: c++

I am designing an application, where multiple geometric primitive types (all inheriting the base `Primitive` class) are stored in an object of class `Scene`.

Instead of having a function in my `main()` that programmatically creates a scene by constructing the primitives and then calling `Scene::add(...)`, I'd like to have some sort of configuration file that is read at runtime.
This would save me from having to recompile every time I change something about the scene, and seems like a general good idea (in case someone else that can't program might need to use my program sometime)

I've devised a little scheme that defines the scene through a `.ini` file like so:

```
[primitivefoo]
type = sphere
pos = 10 20 30
radius = 5.5

[primitivebar]
type = triangle
vertexA = 10 10 -10
vertexB = ...
...
```

You get the idea.

My plan is to have each subclass of `Primitive` register their own method `interpretINI(...)` in the class `Scene`. `Scene` would need some sort of map that maps `string`->`void* (...)`, so that I know which type-string from the `.ini` file corresponds to which subclass of `Primitive`.

If this entire approach is bad design, and there is already a much more elegant way to achieve what I want to achieve, I would love to hear it. If not, I would be very grateful if someone could help me realize my design. I'm stuck on how to iterate over all `Primitive` subclasses to have them register themselves in `Scene`...

Comment: To clarify, the `void*()` I am mapping to would be a static method of the subclass that interprets the data in the `.ini` section and calls the constructor appropriately

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your approach sounds good to me, with the exception that the names should map to a function returning `Primitive*` (instead of `void*`).  This is a factory pattern (on two levels)

One limitation of this approach is that the factory functions registered will have to accept the same number/type of parameters.  [Update: upon reading your comment to your question, this should not be a problem in your case].

I do not know of any automatic way of enumerating subclasses of a particular class, you will need to manually register the known classes (in main, or a special `register` function)

Update: you could get around the subclass enumeration by using static variables (in-class or otherwise) that will run a "register" function specific to the class-in-question:

```
class MyShape : public Shape
{
  static int reg;
  // appropriate constructor
};

int registerMyShape();

int MyShape::reg = registerMyShape(); // this will be called at program startup
```

The only problem is, there is no guarantee about the static initialization order in separate compilation units.  Maybe if you can make the shapes module-like and "load" them after the registry class is fully initialized?

Comment: Thanks, that makes more sense indeed to return the created object straight away :) 

Optimally though, if a different programmer writes a new kind of Primitive, I wouldn't want him to have to edit a different  file to make his class "known"... It seems it would be way more elegant if it became known automagically, maybe through some crazy preprocessor logic?